# How to use pool() on an existing for loop to speed up processing?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, gis

I'm trying to figure out how to use `multiprocessing` in python on the for loop below. I've created a pandas data frame (`data_map`) with the proper amount of rows and columns to fill. The first for loop below works correctly to append data to the correct rows and columns, but because of the nature of the `zonal_stats` function (and working with years of daily raster data across 5000+ census tracts), the function takes approximately 30 seconds to run one iteration, amounting to around two days of run time for all iterations.

```
for n in range(1, len(tract_id_list)):
    
    i = 1
    
    for rast in os.listdir(r'/mnt/local_drive/britton/PRISM_data/PRISM_daily_tmax'):
          if rast[-4: ] == '.tif':
            tmax = rasterio.open(r'/mnt/local_drive/britton/PRISM_data/PRISM_daily_tmax' + '//' + rast)
            tmax_array = tmax.read(1)
            affine = tmax.transform

            tract_average = zonal_stats(tract_polygon[(n-1):n],
                                                        tmax_array,
                                                        affine = affine, 
                                                        stats = ['mean'],
                                                        all_touched = True,
                                                        geojason_out = False)

            tract_average = tract_average[0]['mean']
            
            if n == 1:
                data_map.loc[i]['Date'] = rast[11:-4]
            
            data_map.iloc[(i-1):i, n] = tract_average * 1.8 + 32 # optional conversion to F

            i = i + 1
```

I'm thinking that `pool()` can be used to speed this process up but not sure how to properly implement it. Here is what I've adapted, but when I run it I end up with an empty data frame still:

```
def spatialaverage(value):
    i = 1

    for rast in os.listdir(r'/mnt/local_drive/britton/PRISM_data/PRISM_daily_tmax'):
          if rast[-4: ] == '.tif':
            tmax = rasterio.open(r'/mnt/local_drive/britton/PRISM_data/PRISM_daily_tmax' + '//' + rast)
            tmax_array = tmax.read(1)
            affine = tmax.transform

            tract_average = zonal_stats(tract_polygon[(value-1):value],
                                                        tmax_array,
                                                        affine = affine, 
                                                        stats = ['mean'],
                                                        all_touched = True,
                                                        geojason_out = False)

            tract_average = tract_average[0]['mean']

            if value == 1:
                data_map.loc[i]['Date'] = rast[11:-4]

            data_map.iloc[(i-1):i, value] = tract_average * 1.8 + 32 # optional conversion to F

            i = i + 1

pool_obj = multiprocessing.Pool()
process = pool_obj.map(spatialaverage, range(1, len(tract_id_list)))

data_map
```

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is that each process inherits its own copy of the dataframe and is updating just that local copy.

Since it appears that the real work in `spatialaverage` is being done by the call to `zonal_stats`, which does not need any existing values in the dataframe, I would have only one copy of that dataframe in the main process and then each invocation of `spatialaverage` returns just the values that the main process needs for updating the correct cells with the correct values.

I would arrange the code something like the following. Function `spatialaverage` is now passed a tuple (since the `multiprocessing.pool.imap_unordered` method can only call a "worker" function with a single argument), which is unpacked into 3 variables `n`, `i` and `path` where `n` and `i` are as they were in your original code and `path` is the full path to a tiff file found. So each invocation of `spatialaverage` processes a single value of `n` and `i` (i.e. just one file)

```py
def spatialaverage(tpl):
    n, i, path = tpl # Unpack
    
    tmax = rasterio.open(path)
    tmax_array = tmax.read(1)
    affine = tmax.transform

    tract_average = zonal_stats(tract_polygon[(n-1):n],
                                                tmax_array,
                                                affine = affine, 
                                                stats = ['mean'],
                                                all_touched = True,
                                                geojason_out = False)

    tract_average = tract_average[0]['mean']
    tract_average = tract_average * 1.8 + 32 # optional conversion to F
    return (n, i, tract_average)

# Required for Windows:
if __name__ == '__main__':
    DIR = '/mnt/local_drive/britton/PRISM_data/PRISM_daily_tmax'
    
    data_map = pd.DataFrame(...) # Some dataframe
    tract_id_list = [...] # Some list

    # Process directory once and get a list of all tiff files:    
    rast_list = [rast
                    for rast in os.listdir(DIR)
                    if rast[-4: ] == '.tif'
                ]
    
    # Generate arguments to process:
    def generate_arguments():
        i = 0
        for n in range(1, len(tract_id_list)):
            for rast in rast_list:
                i += 1
                # Handle special case of i == 1:
                if i == 1:
                    data_map.loc[1]['Date'] = rast[11:-4]
                path = f'{DIR}/{rast}'
                yield (n, i, path)
                
    with multiprocessing.Pool() as pool:
        for n, i, tract_average in pool.imap_unordered(spatialaverage, generate_arguments()):
            data_map.iloc[(i-1):i, n] = tract_average
            
    #print(data_map)
```

**Notes**

1. The processing for the special case of `n == 1` when you set `data_map.loc[i]['Date'] = rast[11:-4]`, must be done by the main process since it has the only copy of the dataframe.
2. Method `multiprocessing.pool.imap_unordered` is passed a worker function and a single *iterable*, each element of which represents a new task to be performed by the pool and inplemented by calling your worker function with that argument in one of the pool processes. Unlike method `map`, `imap_unordered` returns an iterator that when iterated produced the next return value from the worker function (also a tuple in this case) *as it is generated* (`map` only returns when all submitted tasks have completed). These return values are not necessarily in the same order as tasks were submitted but rather in task completion order. This presents no issue since we are explicitly passing back from the worker function the information the main process needs for updating the correct cells.
3. I obviously could not test this code and I have made quite a few changes. So please take some time to understand it and make whatever adjustments are required.